# JQuery !== to JQuery, where should I look for problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think there is something going on with a very big browserify build that means that JQuery is being loaded twice, but having real trouble finding it.

As evidence of it I give the following snippet of code

```
var outsidejq = $;
console.log(outsidejq === $);
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log(outsidejq === $);
});
```

produces two outputs, true and false. However since it is a really big complicated build I am wondering if there is any functionality of jquery that would mean the above was to be expected?

I have checked and they are in fact both jquery instances, version 1.11.3

Comment: I don't use jQuery, but that definitely does not sound right to me. Are you passing the `--no-dedupe` option to browserify?

Comment: try `console.log($ === jQuery)`

Comment: Some other script modifies `$`. We can't know what you have in there.

Comment: You can use disc (https://github.com/hughsk/disc) to check what you've bundled, then you can easily check if you bundle jquery once or more  times.

Comment: Thanks! hughsk/disk looks like what I need.